# Android: How to get device id from a Google Analytics even in firebase - functions

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get firebase device id in firebase functions (Node JS)

This is the document that I have referenced.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.analytics.deviceinfo.md#analyticsdeviceinfo_interface

This is how I am trying to get it, but in the logs i can see that its undefined.

```
const deviceId = functions.analytics.DeviceInfo.deviceId;
```

Here is my complete code

```
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    admin.initializeApp();

    const database = admin.firestore();

    exports.appUninstall = functions.analytics.event("app_remove")
      .onLog((event) => {
      
      const deviceId = functions.analytics.DeviceInfo.deviceId;
      
      console.log("deviceId", deviceId);
      
      database.doc("userActivity/uninstalls"+deviceId)
          .update({"device_id": deviceId});

      return console.log("uninstall event called");
    });
```

How can we get the device id through firebase functions.

I am trying to get the device id when we uninstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

By default we get some information in the `event` object and it contains the device info as well but it does not contain the device_id. Now I am looking for ways to add the device_id to the event object.